# Please change the commandline tag to command-line

Tags: discussion, status-completed, retag-request

There are 15 questions tagged command-line and 33 tagged commandline. I think command-line is clearer, but the two tags should be rolled up either way.

Comment: Information got lost in Rich B's edit; should have kept "SU" in the title somewhere. I'll fix by tagging. (Not awfully important now, but just saying.)

Answer (score 3):

Merged <kbd>commandline</kbd> into <kbd>command-line</kbd>
Merged <kbd>cmd</kbd> into <kbd>command-line</kbd>

Answer (score 2):

In favour of <kbd>command-line</kbd> only because it's less of a jumarble of the words when reading.

Feeling is that tags that are multiple words should just include the hyphen (-) instead of jammingthemallintoonewordfor the sake of it.

There's also <kbd>cmd</kbd> to consider, and from the looks of things, deal with the command line anyway.

Answer (score 1):

Yeah, I agree about going with `command-line`. (It's the better option for a couple of reasons, one small one being consistency between SU and SO: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/command-line.)